# Please have a look at my code and guide me why is it throwing this exception "Name [jdbc/test] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]"

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jndi, tomcat9

------------APPLICATION_CONTEXT.xml--------------
I have read alot of articles but didnt find any solution...

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="jdbc/test" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        name="factory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.spring.rest.curd.model.Payment</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>
    </bean>
```

------------CONTEXT.xml-----------

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/test"
global="jdbc/test"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

------------SERVER.xml---------

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/test"
              global="jdbc/test"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
              username="root"
              password="root"
              maxActive="100"
              maxIdle="20"
              minIdle="5"
              maxWait="10000"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jndi-name of the resource has the implicit prefix: `java:comp/env/`

So, if the resource name in your `context.xml` is `jdbc/test`, then the `jndi-name` of your `jndi-lookup` (in `APPLICATION_CONTEXT.xml`) must be `java:comp/env/jdbc/test`.

```
<jee:jndi-lookup
     jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/test"
     id="dataSource"
     expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Comment: its showing up "Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/test] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]."

Comment: @anoopKumar: move the `<Resource>` tag from `server.xml` to `context.xml` and remove the `<ResourceLink>` tag. -- also make sure that the database driver jar is in your tomcat lib directory

Comment: What tag then should i use for <Resource> in server.xml??

Comment: just remove it from `server.xml`

Comment: Its still throwing the same exception

Comment: where exactly is the `context.xml` located?

Comment: src-->main-->webapp-->WEB-INF